# Can't scroll down with mousewheel in my wp website

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using wordpress for a few years now, but I've never found something like this.

Since the last wp version, I can't scroll down in my website using the mousewheel. Scrollbar is there and it works fine, but not the mousewheel.

I'm not an expert, but after being looking for it for hours, I decided to ask stackoverflow community.

So could someone please help me to figure out what is going on here?

The website is: https://daro.es

Thank you everybody!

Comment: I can scroll in google chrome and firefox. What is your web browser ? Also i noticed that you have added a js or jquery script to change the default behavior of the scroll with mousewheel. Maybe this script could have compatibily issues with some browsers or brower's version. We need more details about your configuration. Edit: Also work in safari.

Comment: Hello! sorry for the delay of my answer, my chrome version is:
64.0.3282.167 (official build) (64 bits), in any other browser, it works fine, it's just in chrome that doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, at the end, I figured out what it was.

Apparently, there is an error with the library smoothscroll and cherry framework (themes from templatemonster come with cherry framework). The main problem is, that this framework is using an outdated version of jQuery, and this became a big issue with the last chrome version.

I found the solution into this thread:
http://www.cherryframework.com/question/mousewheel-stops-working-on-google-chrome/

And I used "Fergas" solution.

I hope that this can help somebody!

Regards,
Daniel